# Why SKProductsRequestDelegate/SKRequestDelegate didFailWithError throws EXC_BAD_ACCESS on NSError?

Tags: ios, swift, nserror

I use `SKProductsRequest` to download product infos from App Store.
When I test a connectivity loss on my device, the request fails, but my app crashes within the `SKRequestDelegate` when I try to `NSLog` the error:

[image: crash]

What am I doing wrong ? Another curious thing to me is that Expression Inspector is able to display `NSError.debugDescription`...

It fails on the first request, so there is no possible bug relative to multiple uses of productRequest variable (which is a strong ref in my swift class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the reason. It is not related to `SKProductsRequest`!

I think there is a nasty bug with `NSLog`and string interpolation because when I replace:

```
NSLog("Failed: \(error.debugDescription)")
```

by

```
print("Failed: \(error.debugDescription)")
```

all is fine!

Apparently, the content of the error message can provoke a EXC_BAD_ADDRESS in NSLog (even without string interpolation in fact: `NSLog(error.debugDescription)` fails too).

---

Related anwser: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29631505/249742

`NSLog("%@", error.debugDescription)`

seems to work fine in every cases.

Perhaps `NSLog(variable)` is a misuse of NSLog, but I think `NSLog(\(variable))` should be interpreted like `NSLog("%@", variable)`. Else, there is no reliable way to interpolate strings with NSLog using the swift way `\()`.